# ROP gadget tool to get the ROP chain generation for Windows PE/COFF files

Tags: portable-executable

I'm looking for ROP gadget tools that can get ROP chain generation for Windows PE/COFF files. I tried https://github.com/sashs/Ropper and https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/ROPgadget and actually they both don't support rop chain generation for windows PE/COFF files.

For example, https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/ROPgadget/blob/master/ropgadget/ropchain/ropmaker.py#L34

Do you know any ROP gadget tools that can get ROP chain generation specifically for Windows PE/COFF files?

Please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Ropper does support generating rop chains for Windows, but only for a virtualprotect call (Windows 32bit).

`ropper -f <bin> --chain virtualprotect`